# Windows VCOM implementation

Tags: windows, usb, cdc, virtual-serial-port

I have probably a very simple question.

When I initialize the port in Windows 10 the control message sent to USB device is incomplete. Windows sends the speed, but all other parameters are zeros (ie parity, nbits etc). I have checked the raw data received by the endpoint, I have also sniffed the communication on the cable - and Windows does not send this data.

Is this the standard virtual serial windows driver issue?

Comment: usbser.sys is perfectly able to set parity and other serial port options for a USB CDC ACM device.  I suggest giving more details about your device, its descriptors, its Device Manager entries (i.e.g what driver is it really using), and how exactly you are testing it.

Comment: @DavidGrayson It is 3xCDC on STM32 uC. usbser is used by the devices. Opening the COM port connection sends the configuration packed but unfortunately everything except the speed which is transmitted correctly is always zero.

Comment: Well, in my experience, there is no such problem with usbser.sys, so the problem most likely comes from your testing procedure, which you have not described.  If you have a USB protocol analyzer, you should use it.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I would not ask the question if I have not  done it. Nothing except the speed is sent